# Calculator Program does not compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I wrote a program that implements a simple calculator. However, it does not compile. The compiler says that there are 22 errors, and I don't know why.

**Desired behavior:**

1. Asks user about the desired operation
2. Asks user about the parameters
3. Outputs result

**Specific problem or error:**

Compilation errors at any occurrence of `cin`,`cout`, `endl`, `case` and `break`

[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    float area, r, l, h, b;
    int choice;
    cout<<"\n area of?";
    cout<<"\n[1]square \n[2]rectangle \n[3]circle \n[4]triangle"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice);
    {
    case 1:
        cout<<"enter length"<<endl;
        cin>>l;
        area=l*l;
        cout<<area<<endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout<<"enter height"<<endl;
        cin>>h;
        cout<<"enter length"<<endl;
        cin>>l;
        area=l*h;
        cout<<area<<endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"enter radius"<<endl;
        cin>>r;
        area=r*r*3.14;
        cout<<area<<endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout<<"enter height"<<endl;
        cin>>h;
        cout<<"enter breadth"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        area=h*b*0.5;
        cout<<area<<endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You screwed up the indentation.

Comment: So it's up to us to guess what these 22 errors are???

Comment: `switch(choice);` -> `switch(choice)`. No `;` after `switch`.

Comment: Could you please share error messages?

Comment: "switch(choice)" remove semicolon ";"

Comment: 1) "_but the compiler shows 22 errors_" Typically the errors tell you, exactly, what is wrong. Did you try reading them? 2) "_and i really don't understand the concept of scope too_" Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) then.

Comment: Use `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::endl` for starters.

Comment: @mjcs "_and `using namespace std` is missing_" [`using namespace std` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Sorry, Seto, but _"the compiler shows 22 errors and i really don't understand the concept of scope too so yeah"_ is not really a valid problem description here.

Comment: @mjcs *slaps mjcs with paperroll* Bad contributor, bad! No developer-treats for you tonight! (`using namespace std` is usually considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Let's avoid teaching beginners bad habits.)

Comment: You seem to have misspelt `std::cout`, `std::cin`, and `std::endl`.  But really, this is 22 questions in one - you should be able to reduce your code to just *one* error (and if you did so, you'd likely be able to fix it yourself!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are two errors (compile time errors, at least). First of all, `cin`, `cout` and `endl` are not known, you have to write them as `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

The second problem is here:

```
switch (choice);
```

Remove that semicolon and it's fine. The reson why it's not working with the semicolon is because then `switch (choice);` is its own one and done deal, and the statements after it don't make sense without it.

Also, although it's not causing any compile time errors, I would highly recommend that you indent your code properly. mjcs edited the code you provided for you, it now looks much nicer and it is much easier to find the errors this way. In a big program, it is absolutely vital that the code is indented well, otherwise it's very hard to work with.

Comment: I'd drop the paragraph about `using namespace std;` - or at least word it more strongly that doing so is a very bad idea. (Let's teach beginners good habits, not bad ones. Someone may need to work with her/his code someday. It might be you...)

Comment: Great idea, I got rid of that sentence altogether.